# when the "make -j20" will failed?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

GNU make version 3.81, when I tab make -j20, there are so many errors and warnings. But when tab "make", then it will seccess ? Is there any relation with include "../build/Generic.mak"?
or when make -j20 will failed?

Comment: You are talking about tab completion erroring/warning? Or actually running `make -j20`?

Comment: running make -j20 . 3ks.

Comment: If `make -j20` fails and `make` does not then that usually indicates that the makefiles are not properly written and that there are some unspecified prerequisite relationships that the parallel building that using `-j` triggers has hit one of these situations. There isn't anything you can do about that other then dig in to what exactly failed and how that situation came to be so as to correct the makefiles to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your Makefile is simply not thread safe.  That's why it doesn't work with **-j** parameter.  The **-j** option tells make to run in parallel.

Unfortunately, the Makefile language is too complex to know exactly what is wrong with your build with the information you've given.  It's a rather involved subject but you could try to read (a lot) about GNU make and automake to find some insight.